# Double image size when convert an UIImage to CIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, core-image

Here is my test code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.uiImage = [self imageFromView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Test1: uiImage.size = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.uiImage.size));

    self.ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.uiImage.CGImage];
    NSLog(@"Test1: ciImage.extent = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.ciImage.extent));

    self.uiImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"Test2: uiImage.size = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.uiImage.size));

    self.ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.uiImage.CGImage];
    NSLog(@"Test2: ciImage.extent = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.ciImage.extent));

}

-(UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

and I get the following output:

```
Test1: uiImage.size = {768, 1024}
Test1: ciImage.extent = {{0, 0}, {1536, 2048}}
Test2: uiImage.size = {400, 400}
Test2: ciImage.extent = {{0, 0}, {400, 400}}
```

I could not find why the image size is doubled in Test1. How can I fix it?

Comment: Because of the scale (Retina)? Also in `[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];`, does it returns always the image of size 400*400? Do you use @2x/Assets?

Comment: I did not use @2x. I simply right clicked -> Add files to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIImage` size is in points.  The `CIImage` extent is in pixels.  When you capture the `UIView` for the first test, you are doing so on a retina screen, so 1 point == 2x2 pixels.  When you're loading the second image from a file, you're loading a non-retina asset (`test.jpg` vs `test@2x.jpg`), so 1 point == 1x1 pixels.

There's nothing really to fix – when you capture the view as an image, it's not doubling in size, that's the size – in pixels – of the view you are capturing.

If you want the two tests to end up at the same scale, then supply retina versions of your assets.